# register IRepo<T> to 2 implementations, so that it would resolve it depending on T (interfaces that T implements)

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor, ioc-container, factory

I have something like this:

```
public class IRepo<T>
{
}

public class EntRepo<T> : IRepo<T> where T : Entity
{
}

public classs DelRepo<T> : IRepo<T> where T : Entity, IDel
{
}
```

how would I register this so that when I will `Resolve` an implementation with T that implements `IDel` I would get `DelRepo`, in rest I would get `EntRepo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a decorator / router that knows two which implementation to route. Here's an example:

```
public class RepoRouter<T> : IRepo<T> where T : Entity
{
    private static readonly bool isDelType;
    private readonly IWindsorContainer container;

    static RepoRouter()
    {
        isDelType = typeof(IDel).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T));
    }

    public RepoRouter(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    // Implement all interface members of IRepo<T> here.
    void IRepo<T>.MyInterfaceMethod(T value)
    {
        this.GetRepo().MyInterfaceMethod(value);
    }

    private IRepo<T> GetRepo()
    {
        return isDelType ?
            this.container.Resolve<DelRepo<T>>() :
            this.container.Resolve<EntRepo<T>>();
    }
}
```

You can now register this `RepoRouter<T>` in your container.

Comment: @Steven I'm gonna have to create a SomeRepoAction for each method of the IRepo right ?

Comment: @Omu: You need to implement the `IRepo<T>` interface for your `RepoRouter<T>`. The `SomeRepoAction` is an example, because I don't know how your `IRepo<T>` interface looks like. I updated my example. Hopefully it's a bit more clear now.

Comment: @Steven is this actually the decorator pattern ?

Comment: @Omu: I think this counts as an implementation of the decorator pattern :-)

Comment: @Steven doesn't look like decorator, its 3 classes that implement the same interface and the third is like a facade that uses the first 2

Comment: @Omu: Perhaps the proxy design pattern comes closer. Both patterns delegate work to a wrapped or real instance, as this solution does. Regardless of how we label it, I hope it helps you in finding a solution for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `IHandlerSelector`........